# Getting the scrollTop() value of an element inside an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is it possible to get the scrollTop or offSet value of an element inside an iFrame? e.g

```
$("iframe").contents(".controlPanel").scrollTop();
```

or any other way possible?

I get a return value of `null`

Comment: Have a look at this previously asked question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page

Comment: @MaartenVenema I need to invoke a function within my page but get the contents of the iframe to evaluate, If the function was in my iframe content that would be easier, also note that I dont have access to the iframe content. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you addressed that you have no influence over the iframe's content there is no way to invoke JavaScript inside of it. This has to do with cross-domain policies.